# Make transform.up face toward velocity while preventing transform.forward from rolling?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, movement

I have been working on a personal project that is suppose to mimic Anthem. I am using a state machine for the character controller that I intend to integrate with the Unity's Animation state machine.

I am calculating a new velocity that makes the player follow the mouse when flying, and I am making `transform.up = Velocity` so that the player appears to be going head first towards its velocity.

The issue is that when you start to rotate in a circular way on the xz plane, the player will start to roll and its `transform.forward` moves from facing towards the ground (which is what I want) to facing the sky.

[image: Animation of roll]

The core code is in `public override Update()`:

```
public class s_MechFlyt : MechStates{

  float flySpeedPercentage;

  public s_MechFlyt(in MechController Master) : base(Master){
    flySpeedPercentage = 2.5f;
  }

  public override void Update(){
    if (_Master.SprintButtonHeld){

      Quaternion Rot = Quaternion.Euler(-_Master.DMouse.y , _Master.DMouse.x , 0);

      _Master.Velocity = Rot * Vector3.forward * _Master.Stats.Speed * flySpeedPercentage;
      Vector3 Rotation = _Master.Velocity;**
      //Rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(Rotation.z, 0, 50);
      _Master.transform.up = Vector3.Normalize(Rotation);
      //_Master.transform.rotation = Rot;

      //_Master.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(_Master.transform.up, _Master.Velocity, 5);

      _Master._Controller.Move(_Master.Velocity * Time.deltaTime);

      if (_Master.JumpButtonHeld){
        _Master.ChangeStates("hover");
        _Master.transform.up = Vector3.up;
      }

    }
    else{
      _Master.ChangeStates("fall");
      _Master.transform.up = Vector3.up;
    }
  }

  public override void EnterState(){
    _Master.CamController.ChangeStates("flying");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a rotation that points `Vector3.forward` in the direction of flight, while keeping `Vector3.up` as vertical as it can.

Pitching that rotation forward 90 degrees means it points `Vector3.up` in the direction of flight, and points `Vector3.forward` down.

```
Quaternion mouseRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-_Master.DMouse.y , _Master.DMouse.x , 0);

_Master.Velocity = mouseRotation * Vector3.forward * _Master.Stats.Speed * flySpeedPercentage;

_Master.transform.rotation = mouseRotation * Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That worked exactly as I wanted! thanks!